# Why does the price of a butterfly spread increase are rate exponential

Tags: options, option-pricing, portfolio-management, hedging, replication

[image]

[image]

I know that stock prices are assumed to be Stochastic processes that follow Geometric brownian motion. The expectation of stock prices at time T given stock price at time 0 is: $e^{-rT}S_0$. However, why would the price of a portfolio containing a some calls and no underlying stock, as it is defined above, have the same property?